# Power variables in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently making a binomial distribution calculator in C++. Currently having problems with the math,

```
cout << pow(p,x);  //working (Prints probably to the power of x)
```

for example, I tried `0.2^5` and it printed `0.00032` which is correct.

However:

```
pToN=pow(p,x); 

cout << pToN;
```

for the same power it returns `0`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pToN is supposed to be float, I assume it is not.

Comment: What is pToN, in C++ you should define variables before using them.

Comment: do provide a complete example that exhibits the problem

Answer (score 0):

`pToN` should be a float so that it can hold non-whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

if `pToN` is `int` it will be truncated. `pow` returns `double`. So change the declaration of `pToN` to `double pToN;`(or `float`)

Comment: of course, `pToN` is *not* `int`, as you're Just Guessing(TM), but the type `struct Boo{ Boo( double ){} operator char const*() const { return "0"; } };` [edit: after i wrote this comment the answer was changed to "if". but i think it represents a common ungood practice on SO. so i let it stand]

Answer (score 0):

The `pow` function returns `float` or `double`, so the `pToN` should be declared as `float` or `double`